# How to validate git clone/pull files match server?

Tags: git

What is the best way to ensure that the files that git pulled down match what is on the GIT server? Is there a way to get the remote file's checksum hash?

Reason: Our repo has multi gigabyte files and we've had issues (on Windows) with `git pull` not pulling down the complete file. We are using `git lfs` too which seems flaky but seems to work. We are writing a process to migrate the files from GIT to another data store and we want to ensure the files we pull are complete before pushing into the new data store.

Note: I will be running the migration process on Linux which has shown no issues pulling the large files. The business has requested this extra validation step due to their experience with unsuccessful pulls.

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by "on the server"? Do you mean the git server? Some application server?

Comment: When you `git pull` from a repository, you will always get the files that match what is stored on the git server since you are pulling the files from there.

Comment: I mean... part of the reason for using a version control system such as git is to ensure that everyone is working on the correct version of the codebase, no?

Comment: Additional details have been added to the question.

Comment: `git pull` does not pull *files*. It fetches, then merges or rebases, *commits*. Commits have internal self-consistency checking; it's not possible to fetch a partial commit, and `git fsck` will detect corrupted commits, including any corruption of files contained within them. I'd suggest avoiding `git pull` entirely since it is more likely to be the *merge* step that is producing poor results, and you can insert whatever checking you like around that step.